# How to pass an array of numbers to Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: arrays, oracle, numbers

To pass an array of number to oracle stored procedure, I created a type like this:

```
create or replace type wareconfig_array as table of NUMBER;
```

Then I created my procedure like this, when I compile, it shows success, then I pass an array like: **[1,2]** to **m_array** when I run it, it throws an error: **"ORA-06531:Reference to uninitialized collection"** Can you tell me what I did wrong? Thanks very much!

```
create or replace procedure delete_waregroup(m_array in wareconfig_array) is
begin
  for i in 1..m_array.count loop
      update "warehouse_group" set "deleted"=1 where "id"=m_array(i);
  end loop;
  commit;
EXCEPTION
   when others THEN
        save_proc_error('proc',sqlcode,'删除仓库组信息发生异常！',sqlerrm);
        raise_application_error(-20003,'数据操作异常！异常编码：'|| sqlcode || '异常描述：'|| sqlerrm||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());
        rollback; ---回滚
end delete_waregroup;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
declare 
   x wareconfig_array;
begin
  x := wareconfig_array(1,3); -- initialize an array and fill it with values
  delete_waregroup( x );
end;
/
```

live (working) demo:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af403e/1